# Avataravaada and vedanta, are there any contradiction?

Tags: puranas, avatars, vedanta

What is stance of Vedanta on the concept of avatara? Does Vedanta support that god comes to earth in form of a human?

Comment: What is avatarbad?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Avataravada means the formless Brahma taking human, animal, bird et cetera forms to come to earth and remove afflictions of devotees.

Comment: Vedanta is broad. You can ask specific philosophy in Vedanta.

Comment: Related [How does Adishankaracharya Advaita explain concept of Avatar?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14114/3500)

Comment: OP- Please use the correct Sanskrit spellings of words. @AnuragSingh -Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Dvaita Vedanta and Vishistadvaita Vedanta accept the concept of Avatara.

Advaita Vedanta does not accept the concept of Avatara. Advaita Vedanta claims that the Avatara is same as a Jnani. Any distinction between Avatara and Jnani would contradict scripture.

> D.: The avatars are said to be more glorious than the self-realized
>   Jnanis. Maya does not affect them from birth; divine powers are
>   manifest; new religions are started; and so on.
>
> M (Sri Ramana).: (1)"Jnani tvatmaiva me matam."
>                    (2)"Sarvam khalvidam brahma." 
>   **How is an avatar different from Jnani; or how can there be an avatar as distinct from
>   the universe?**
>
> D.: The eye (chakshu) is said to be the repository (ayatana) of all
>   forms; so the ear (srotra) is of all sounds, etc. This one Chaitanya
>   operates as all; no miracles are possible without the aid of the sense
>   (indriyas). How can there be miracles at all? If they are said to
>   surpass human understanding so are the creations in dreams. Where then
>   is the miracle? **The distinction between avataras and Jnanis is absurd.
>   "Knower of Brahman becomes Brahman only" is otherwise contradicted.**
>
> M.: **Quite so.**

Talks with Sri Ramana Maharshi, pg 443-444

Comment: Swami Vivekananda says no matter how advanced someone is, they cannot take the position of God and avatars are different from ordinary guru, avatar can change destiny of someone, ordinary guru can't.

Comment: You are correct. Swami Vivekananda did not always agree with Sankaracharya's Advaita Vedanta.

Comment: Advaita Vedanta doesn't contradict Avatara. Adi Shankara accepted words of Krishna on Avataras, Iswara aka Saguna Brahman takes Avatara in Vyavaharika. See [How does Adishankaracharya Advaita explain concept of Avatar?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14114/how-does-adishankaracharya-advaita-explain-concept-of-avatar/14123)

Comment: I looked at the question referred by you. If you read the Gambhirananda quote it says,'He appears as if embodied, as if born, and as if favoring people-..'. It is all 'as if' and not real. Moreover Sri Ramana's asserts that there is no distinction between Avatara and Jnani. Advaita Vedanta does not accept the theistic view of Avatara and reduces the Avatara to the status of a Jnani.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay  Any support from writings of Gaudapada or Sankara for claim that advaita vedanta doesn't accept avataravada?  Ramana Maharashi taught from self experience, he didn't restrict himself so as to be faithful to advaita vedanta or any other school.  Check out last few paras in this link. http://sri-ramana-maharshi.blogspot.in/2010/04/swami-siddheswaranandas-views-on.html?m=1

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay Merely appearing as having born, as being embodied etc is indeed what differentiates an avatara from mere jivanmukta. Jivanmukta is really born just like rest of us. He is really embodied like rest of us until he attains self realisation. While avatara is just leela of saguna brahman which rest of us see as being born, growing up, dying etc.

Comment: This seems to say the opposite re: advaita https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14114/1195

Comment: Advaitins believe that there is a distinction between incarnations of Saguna Brahman and other Jivas.  The distinction is this: the bodies of other Jivas are formed out of Karmas, whereas the bodies of avataras are formed out of the compassion of Saguna Brahman.  Now you might say that this is only an apparent distinction, not a real distinction, and that is true, but only insofar as all distinctions are ultimately apparent according to Advaita; Advaitins believe that only Nirguna Brahman is ultimately real from the absolute perspective.