# What separates the Avatar from Atman and Paramatman

Tags: avatars, atma

As the Avatar is seen or has been seen in his physical or ethereal body, both without and within. What separates him from Atman and Paramatman ?

Comment: Paramatman is not in the control of maya, Atman is in the control of maya

Comment: [Related not Duplicate] [How does Adishankaracharya Advaita explain concept of Avatar?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14114/3500)

Comment: There are various physical signs of Avatara described by the vaishnavas

Answer (score 2):

Atman is the Self which can be accessed from within.

Paramatman is Universal Self that starts from the Atman and permeates the whole Universe.

Refer: **Upadesha Saram:** Verse 24 onwards

http://www.advaidam.com/2016/10/05/upadesa-saram-class-11/

***Warning**: The site has some malicious script and hence please don't click the page. Hence added snapshots of the page.*

> [image: verses 24-25]

> [image: Verse 26]

Avatar is any being that is fully realized and is aware of it's Universal Self and also of the fact that it has a body to work with on the Earthly plane of consciousness.

Comment: How about supporting your answer with some references?

Comment: Namaste Welcome to HSE! You can have a look the help centre on answering questions as well as [guidelines for new users](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)