# Is the Divine Body of Krishna beyond Nirguna and Saguna?

Tags: krishna, gunas

The phenomenal and celestial realms are filled with the constant ebb and flow of the gunas which are sattva, rajas and tamas.

Is the Divine Body of Krishna made from gunas, or is he there in these realms but his body is not made of the gunas?

Is the Divine Body of Krishna beyond Nirguna and Saguna, ie beyond the gunas?

Comment: again, primarily opinion based. vote to close.

Comment: You are confused. Nirguna is Satchidananda (sat+chid+Ananada)- ever existing pure blissful consciousness. Advaita Vedanta primarily emphasizes Nirguna Brahman. As per Advaita, Nirguna Brahman sees just Nirguna Brahman and there is Sat-Chid-Ananda and nothing else. In Maya, Nirguna appears as Saguna (Vishnu, Shiva, Brahma and other Gods). Even Avataras such as Rama and Krishna are Saguna and this is as per Advaita Vedanta only. See [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14114/3500).

Comment: Rephrase the question to conform to the prescribed format.  This query is otherwise purely opinion based.

Answer (score 7):

Lord Krishna's body is not made of gunas, He is beyond these gunas since He is Brahman.

In the chapter [Prayers by Queen Kuntī and Parīkṣit Saved](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/8/18) of Srimad Bhagavatham - 1.8.18  Kunti prays to Lord Krishna as:

> Śrīmatī Kuntī said: O Kṛṣṇa, I offer my obeisances unto You because You are the original personality and **are unaffected by the qualities of the material world.** You are existing both within and without everything, yet You are invisible to all.

Also from the chapter [The Passing Away of Bhīṣmadeva in the Presence of Lord Kṛṣṇa](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/9/21) of Srimad Bhagavatham - 1.9.21, by addressing Lord Krishna Bhishma says,

> Being the Absolute Personality of Godhead, He is present in everyone’s heart. He is equally kind to everyone, and **He is free from the false ego of differentiation. Therefore whatever He does is free from material inebriety. He is equibalanced.**

And as user Hayagreev Ram said, these gunas affects material residents and not for Lord Krishna who is the source of everything.

Answer (score 4):

Krishna is above all these three qualities. Sattva, Rajas and Tamas affect only the residents of Samsara. As he says in the Bhagavad Gita 18.40:

> **na tad asti pṛthivyāṁ vā 
>
> divi deveṣu vā punaḥ** | 
> **sattvaṁ prakṛti-jair muktaṁ 
>
> yad ebhiḥ syāt tribhir guṇaiḥ** ||
>
> There is no being existing, either here or among the demigods in the higher planetary systems, which is freed from these three modes born of material nature.

So, since Krishna/Vishnu resides in the spiritual world, he is not affected by them at all. His body is also not affected by such Gunas. He is completely pure. Now, this pure does not indicate Sattva, as a Sattvic life also has parts of Rajas and Tamas. Since he is above all the three, he is completely pure.

Comment: Ya the veil of Samskaras consisting of the gunas, sattva, rajas and tamas is understood. In Autobiography of a Yogi by Paramahansa Yogananda he says he was visited by Krishna, is this his eternal body and is it beyond Nirguna and Sarguna ?