# Did even wisest persons, who followed Dharma in Mahabharata had false beliefs about castes?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma, karna, dronacharya

I have seen these things so many times. In TV serials, in my high school brief Mahabharata book and at many online resources:

**Dronacharya** didn't accept Karna as his disciple, as he was **soot-putra**. At this, Karna explains the truth, that low/high castes have nothing to do with your skills. You can learn anything and you have right to do so. Still Drona didn't agree.

**Parshuram** only accepted Karna as disciple when he said he is Brahmin. And at the end of his education, when the incident took place that revealed the truth, he said that a Brahmin can't have so much strength/patience, only a Kshatriya has such powers.

What is the truth? Did they have wrong beliefs? Or truth is something else?

This is so disappointing to me, as both of them were Avatars of Brahma and Vishnu. How can they believe like this?

Comment: Any source wherw Drona is mentioned as an  avtar of Brahma?? As per MBH, Drona was born from a portion of rishi Vrihaspati...

Comment: I read on Wikipedia: *In the epic Mahabharata, Droṇa (Sanskrit: द्रोण, Droṇa) or Droṇāchārya or Guru Droṇa or Rajaguru Devadroṇa was the 3rd incarnation of Brahma and was royal preceptor to the Kauravas and Pandavas; an avatar of Brihaspati. *

Comment: Please Read Mahabharata,It is very long of 200000 verses,Read as much as you can as Tv serials only potray wrong information. Mahabharata contains every situation a human can face and it portrays almost every value of Dharma.

Comment: tv series are not a source.

Answer (score 1):

[Drona](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01135.htm) did not deny Karna, the knowledge of archery.   Karna could not excel Arjuna as he did not have the determination.

> Then Drona endued with great prowess taught the sons of Pandu (the use of) many weapons both celestial and human. And, O bull of the Bharata race, many other princes also flocked to that best of Brahmanas for instruction in arms. The Vrishnis and the Andhakas, and princes from various lands, and the (adopted) son of Radha of the Suta caste, (Karna), all became pupils of Drona.

---

With his previous experience with Bhishma, Parasurama decided not to teach archery to Kshatriyas.

So if Karna  learnt archery  fraudulently,  it was his mistake and he had to reap the consequences.

---

By the way the incarnation concept is a myth.

Comment: *incarnation concept is a myth* You're ruining it :( Everything is fake? Just a story like Harry Potter?

Comment: I could not get you.  What do you mean by ruining? @Vikas Kumar

Comment: I thought Mahabharata is  true story and Krishna and other main characters' avatars were true story, not a myth.

Comment: @VikasKumar: I never stated that Mahabharata is a false story.  What I had stated that incarnation concept is a myth, as the incarnation stories were added at a later date. (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/34975/3869)

Comment: I think crores of Indian believe in incarnations. If this thing is wrong, there is a strong chance Mahabharata is just an entertainment story.

Comment: @VikasKumar just one thing I will say. The belief system was never in hinduism. Hinduism never believed anything. If anyone wants to see Vishnu, or Shiva or Brahma, they go and do tapasya as per proper methods. Its not belief. its acceptance of reality. If you understand how Indian history was , and lifestyle before invasions correctly than reading British projected false things, you can understand Mahabharata, Ramayana are histories. Ithihasa meaning itself is history. Its about understanding and getting clarity. Not believing! Belief can swing either ways but understanding is permanent!

Comment: @srimannarayanakv myth has two meanings. Which one you're talking about?

Comment: fake stuff. Drona was instructed that he teach the children of the kings and later in BR chopra mahabharat, drona tells karna that in his gurukula, save for his son, he could only teach kids who belonged to royal families and even apologized and tells he found a better teacher than himself which is Parashurama. That is when Karna tells that even though he became highly skilled, Karna got cursed