# When paramatma can control souls why does he need various weapons?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, krishna, weapon

When paramatma can control his own souls why does he fight with weapons ?

[image: Image of Krishna holding various weapons]

Comment: Weapons are just symbols you need to decipher the meaning of the weapons Hindusim is cryptic.. The same scripture mean different thing to different people. If you need to understand a bit you need to learn upanishad, mahabrata, ramayana, all the 18 puranas, after this skisha, vakhyarana, niruktha, kalpa, joythisaa and chandas all this are essiential part to decipher the meaning in vedas, otherwise it will be like maze leading you to opposite way.. if you read it from the surface level understanding it may be devastating

Comment: Even though the weapons symbolise something they fight with asuras with these weapons.Why does he need to fight for thousands of years and get tired as described in some puranas and not simply takeback the soul which is an insignificant part of himself ?

Comment: that right fighting asura mean what it meant you only you need to fight your tendencies of going astray day in and day out this innate tendencies are due to your past action.. this is what is meant now in the surface 1000 of years fighting,, this seems to but joke for god what is not possible will he tired fighting at all what happens if he sleeps.. all this if you think you will understand.. that god cannot be tired need not fight than what does it convey

Comment: many people cannot understand abstract concepts. people understand the power of weapons and a person who can wield these weapons easily. it is meant to convey this idea to us who have difficulty with more abstract concepts.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of God is Abstract.

However, different people understood it differently, and expressed their expressions according to their perceptions.

When Arjuna asked Sri Krishna to show his Divine form - द्रष्टुमिच्छामि ते रूपमैश्वरं पुरुषोत्तम, Sri Krishna says as follows:

> इहैकस्थं जगत्कृत्स्नं पश्याद्य सचराचरम्।
>
> मम देहे गुडाकेश **यच्चान्यद्द्रष्टुमिच्छसि**।।11.7।।
>
> Now behold, O Arjuna, in this, My body, the whole universe centred in one including the moving and the unmoving and whatever else thou desirest to see.

And, what did Arjuna see?  He describes the Viswavupa as possessed of numerous arms, bellies, mouths and eyes; as having infinite forms all around.

> किरीटिनं गदिनं चक्रिणं च
>
> तेजोराशिं सर्वतोदीप्तिमन्तम्।
>
> पश्यामि त्वां दुर्निरीक्ष्यं समन्ता
>
> द्दीप्तानलार्कद्युतिमप्रमेयम्।।11.17।।
>
> I see You as wearing a diadem, wielding a mace, and holding a disc; a mass of brilliance glowing all around, difficult to look at from all sides, possessed of the radiance of the blazing fire and sun, and immeasurable.

The secret of Vishwarupa lies in the above Sloka, wherein Sri Krishna said -यच्चान्यद्द्रष्टुमिच्छसि   - whatever else thou desirest to see.

Sri Krishna never said that I am showing the Vishwarupa to you and that these all comprise my Vishwarupa.

He simply said that "See whatever you want to see - यच्चान्यद्द्रष्टुमिच्छसि ".

So whatever Arjuna saw during Viswarupa Sandarsana, it was his own mind's projections and imaginations.

Similarly, attributing different weapons, vehicles to the God, is according to one's own perception.

We hear from the scriptures that the God is All powerful.  So does the God need to carry weapons to achieve anything?

Did Sri Krishna go the assembly of Kauravas with weapons?

Comment: Sir you mean to say vishwa roopa darshana is mere preception of Arjuna.. is it not real.. wow..@srimannarayana k v

Comment: @PrasannaR:: It did not say Vishwa Roopa darshana is mere perception of Arjuna.  What I said was, Sri Krishna did give opportunity to Arjuna to see the Divine form.  However, Vishwa Roopa will be according to one's own maturity in SPIRITUAL line. Arjuna was undoubtedly one of the greatest warriors of his time, but as far as SPIRITUALITY is concerned, his maturity had been at lower level.  That was why he had the vision of Vishwa Roopa according to his understanding. Many saints said in the past that when they merged in the ABSOLUTE BLISS there will be no words to explain.

Comment: "The secret of Vishwarupa lies in the above Sloka, wherein Sri Krishna said -यच्चान्यद्द्रष्टुमिच्छसि - whatever else thou desirest to see."  - Wonderful observation! Gives a completely different perspective.

Comment: Actually I had so many questions about Viswarupa. Now I dont need to ask them because यच्चान्यद्द्रष्टुमिच्छसि answers everything. Thanks for highlighting this.