# Are many peetadhipathis pseudo Vedantists?

Tags: vedanta, terminology

The term Pseudo Vedantist has been explained by Swami Sivananda in an article called ["Pseudo-Vedantic Student"](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=787).

> Vedanta in the hands of raw and unregenerate persons who lack purity
> and devotion and who have not removed the impurity of their hearts
> through untiring selfless service with Atma-Bhava and Kirtan and
> prayer, is perilous. It is like a sharp razor in the hands of a child.
> Instead of expanding their hearts the Vedantic study will thicken and
> fatten their egoism. They fall into the deep abyss of ignorance. There
> is no hope, for them, of being lifted up, as their heart is filled
> with foolish, Tamasic, obstinacy, false Vedantic pride and
> self-superiority and false Tushti (satisfaction).

Does any scripture mention or explain the term Pseudo Vedantism, which many of the peetadhipathis appear to be following?

***Edit 24-7-2020***

The question [How to tell if your guru is god-realized?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7893/how-to-tell-if-your-guru-is-god-realized), as suggested by [Swami Vishwananda](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/882/swami-vishwananda), is different.

Comment: That was quick. I thought you were going to wait a few days as seen in the comments under this answer https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1938/18974

Comment: @Carmensandiego Interesting!

Comment: I altered the question slightly to mention the title of the article. Also, does the article itself talk about Peethadhipatis being pseudo or is it your own question?

Comment: @Rickross: After observing many peethadhipatis or babas, etc, being named in various scandals, I posted this question.

Comment: Okay .. @srimannarayanakv

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell if your guru is god-realized?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7893/how-to-tell-if-your-guru-is-god-realized)

Comment: I feel the quoted text is vague and very qualitative in its language. Very hard to judge who is a "pseudo-Vedantist" from this.