# God as preceptor for self realization

Tags: moksha

Can a spiritual aspirant take the Almighty as the preceptor and tread along the spiritual path and finally attain Self Realization?

Comment: Related not duplicate [Where can I find a guru](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7834/3500) and [How do I find the right Guru](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2394/3500)