# Procedure to make God(s) our Guru

Tags: gods, guru, kashmiri-shaivism, initiation

How one can make any God as one's guru? What is the procedure? Provided one is unable to find/get a Guru due to many reasons. E.g, I am interested in Kashmiri Shaivism but it is very difficult to find Guru being busy in the Job. And also when I can't wait.

Note: Any god is acceptable, I will just consider him/her Guru & continue my Sadhna according to Kashmiri Shaivism.

Comment: That is for extremely rare cases. Finding Gurus is on the other hand is extremely easy . You can easily get Shiva mantra diksha if u are eager for it.

Comment: Please tell rare cases. @Rickross

Comment: Also i don't think the rule will work for you. Because u are not living in deserted island or in a mleccha desha. So the point is if u want u can come in contact with a Guru or a Shaiva Guru and take diksha from him. So ur reason for not having a regular diksha is not strong enough. The rule will deem u unfit. :)

Comment: @Rickross KS Gurus are rare.

Comment: KS gurus don't have any special Shiva mantras to give. Mantras are those which are contained in the scriptures. Take diksha from any Shaivite sampradaya. Check beforehand if you are having respect for ur would be Guru or not. If u think- he is fit to be my Guru, i can respect him like Shiva immediately take mantra from him. Don't wait for Ks Gurus.

Comment: Thanks bro @Rickross  I would think on this. But you can answer also if available. :P

Comment: I have never read anything of that sort so far. I mean the procedure. But I have seen that accepting Gods as Gurus is a possibility in one website. You told me earlier that RYT have mentioned the process.

Comment: Yes @Rickross It has mentioned I think. But there Scripture is made guru.

Comment: @rickross _"Also i don't think the rule will work for you."_ Why not? If someone want to make their Lord to be his/her Guru, then what's the problem? I have read somewhere that in which form we worship our lord, we gets our Lord in that same form. For ex. People worship Lord in diff form like as Father, son, friend, husband etc. And they got Lord in the same form. Then why we can't accept Lord as our Guru since we can accept as all other relations? I personally has thought in mind to consider Hanuman as my Guru because I want only Hanuman as guru, no one else. So what's issue in this? and why?

Comment: Was your Guru Hanuman Guruless? Was ur Ishta Deva (Rama) Guruless during his life? What you have learned from them if you have not taken the most vital clues. Actually Hinduism starts with Guru and ends with Guru. @Rishabh

Comment: @rickross _"Was your Guru Hanuman Guruless?"_ What's your point here? First of all Hanuman is not my guru yet. I said I have thought to make him my guru but haven't made yet. And secondary, I know Hanuman and Rama had Gurus.. that's why I also want to have guru. I can't see any issue in seeing our own Lord as Guru also. Devotee sees their lord as son(Yashodha), as friend(sudama), as husband(Ganga) then why we can't see as Guru? According to me there is no restriction on that what relation we want to make with our Lord.

Comment: 1) I said I have thought to make him my guru but haven't made yet---- But how can u make him your Guru? What's the procedure? How are u sure whether such method is at all found in scriptures? 2)  that's why I also want to have guru----- That's nice to know. 3)  **I can't** see any issue in seeing your own Lord as Guru also. **According to me** there is no restriction on that what relation we want to make with our Lord. ----- But it is not important what is true according to you. You should see what's being followed over the ages and what's prescribed in Scriptures.

Comment: "Also i don't think the rule will work for you." Why not?--- That's because accepting Gods as Guru is an Apaddharma or duties to be followed during emergencies. Such duties and duties that are to be followed during normal times are different. And, Rohit is not exactly in an emergency. So, that's why i said so.@Rishabh

Comment: There are some initiations that can be done only by Guru/Gods in physical body, answer to "how to find the right guru" seems relevant https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2394/how-do-i-find-the-right-guru/27306#27306 and Swami Nithyananda is the most popular Kashmir Shaivism Guru out there

Comment: @Akhil i think you are confused between Nityananda of ganeshpuri and Nityananda of South India ?

Comment: No @RakeshJoshi, both are from South, Nithyananda of Ganeshpuri is no longer in body, but Swami Nithyananda is very much in body and  MahaMandaleshwar of MahaNirvani akhara (a shaivaite tradition) of Akhada Parishad

Comment: @Akhil get your facts right... The Nityananda you are talking is not from KS tradition...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi respectfully yes one cannot be part of MahaNirvani if not a Shaivaite, and in one of the interviews to Rajiv Malhotra in detail explains about his Agamic tradition based on Kashmir Shaivism. If you think otherwise which tradition does he belong to ?

Comment: @Akhil akhadas are not from Kashmir shaiva lineage. Further Nityananda of TN has involved in many scandals etc. I don't think he belongs to kashmir lineage. He would have learned from someone in tiruvannamalai

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76910/discussion-between-akhil-and-rakesh-joshi).

Comment: IstaDevata's is exactly for this, the feeling connection you have with IstaDevata connects you to entire divinity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This page](https://www.manblunder.com/articlesview/self-initiation-of-mantras) gives a reasonably easy to follow and a scriptural method by which one , who does not have a Guru Diksha but desperately in need of one, can make Lord Dakshinamurthy his/her Guru.

> As much as possible, one must try and obtain a guru, to guide with
>   mantras and properly initiate the devotee or sādhakā. **But often, we
>   are faced with a situation, where we cannot find an appropriate guru
>   to guide us. In such situations, one can go ahead and initiate
>   themselves. The procedure to initiate, as well as guidance from the
>   śāstras or scriptures, is provided below.**

The Prayoga needs to be done on the Trayodashi Krishna Paksha. The Sanskrit verses quoted from Agama Rahasyam 4th Chapter say that it has to be done in a temple of Lord Shiva/Dakshinamurty. But the author says that if that is not possible then the same procedure can be followed in one's own house too in front of an image of Lord Dakshinamurty.

> gurorabhāve mantrāṇāṃ grahaṇa krama mucyate।
>
> kṛṣṇapakṣe trayodaśyāṃ dakṣiṇāmūrti sannidhe॥
>
> गुरोरभावे मन्त्राणां ग्रहण क्रम मुच्यते।
>
> कृष्णपक्षे त्रयोदश्यां दक्षिणामूर्ति सन्निधे॥
>
> labhitvā rājate pātre tālapatre'dhavāpunaḥ।
>
> mantraṃ tatstaṃḍile stāpya pūjaitvā maheśvaram॥
>
> लभित्वा राजते पात्रे तालपत्रेऽधवापुनः।
>
> मन्त्रं तत्स्तंडिले स्ताप्य पूजैत्वा महेश्वरम्॥
>
> pāyasādi nivedyaṃ ca kṛtvā taṃpraṇi patyaca।
>
> śatākṛtaḥ paṭhenmantraṃ dakṣiṇāmūrti sannidhau॥
>
> sarveṣāṃcaiva mantrāṇāmevaṃ grahāṇa miṣyate॥
>
> पायसादि निवेद्यं च कृत्वा तंप्रणि पत्यच।
>
> शताकृतः पठेन्मन्त्रं दक्षिणामूर्ति सन्निधौ॥
>
> सर्वेषांचैव मन्त्राणामेवं ग्रहाण मिष्यते॥
>
> āgama rahasyaṃ caturtha paṭhale (śloka 42-44)
>
> आगम रहस्यं चतुर्थ पठले (श्लोक ४२-४४)

The first line itself "gurorabhāve mantrāṇāṃ grahaṇa krama mucyate" means "in the absence of the Guru the following is the process for getting self-initiated into a Mantra".

*Translation*

> The above ślokas state that anyone interested in initiating himself,
>   due to the non-availability of a proper guru, may do so on the 13th
>   lunar day (trayodaśi) of the dark phase of the lunar cycle
>   (kṛṣṇapakṣa). The devotee must visit a śiva temple and pray to Lord
>   dakṣiṇāmūrti, who’s placed in the southern direction within the same
>   temple. If the Lord dakṣiṇāmūrti idol is not present, then one can
>   seek the idol of Lord śiva or nandi (the bull facing the śiva liṇga)
>   and on a silver sheet, or if not available a brass sheet, or further a
>   palm leaf or just a simple paper, write the mantra related to the
>   mantra japa, that one wishes to perform. Place the sheet in front of
>   the aforementioned idol and sincerely perform the puja or prayer to
>   seek the guidance from the Lord, requesting Him to be the guru and
>   praying for the success of the mantra japa. If a temple is not
>   accessible, then one can pray to the idol or image of Lord
>   dakṣiṇāmūrti also.

IMO, this is reasonably very easy to follow. And, one can try it when one can not find the right Guru.

Answer (score 2):

Laya Yoga deals with this. Istadevatha: a replica of Ishta- dewata as an object of concentration is made.For this purpose, a gross image from some suitable material is made. This image is not an imaginary representation of lshtadewata., but a close copy of the real form. It is a tangible form easy for the sense-consciousness to hold.

'Ishtadewata is God in form. The form arises from the living mantra and is created by God himself. So it is not imaginary. God appears in form, otherwise the mind will not be able to receive it. It is absolutely necessary to have a form which can be held in consciousness in concentration. Source: Laya Yoga.