# How to consider Lord Dakshinmurthy as my Guru?

Tags: shiva, guru

It is said that if a person doesn't have a Guru, then they can consider and worship Lord Dakshinamurthy as their Guru. Is there any ritual or mantra to do so?

Comment: Those who don't have Guru yet are asked to chant the following verse before starting a Puja etc: **Nidhaye sarvavidyanam bhishaje bhavaroginam |
Gurave sarvalokanam daxinamurtaye namah ||**. But I'm not sure whether I can post this as an answer or not.

Comment: Can you give the source of this verse?

Comment: It is actually verse # 4 of the Dakshinamurty Stotram composed by Adi Shankara. http://greenmesg.org/stotras/shiva/dakshinamurthy_stotram.php

Comment: Also, any particular way or method prescribed in scriptures for worshipping God by those who don't have Guru yet?

Comment: No I don't know of any such methods. The Tantras in fact (in which Guru's position is ultimate) severely criticize the act of remaining uninitiated (i.e to remain without a Guru).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Looks like a Guru is necessary for guiding us towards Moksha.

Comment: Yes that's very much true.:)

Comment: Probably there are no such rituals. But u can accept him as the Guru mentally.

Comment: I am trying to do that.

Comment: Rishx - A scriptural method is given in my answer here:  https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29929/4732