# Procedure for getting mantra siddhi without Guru initiation

Tags: scripture, mantras, guru

In general, guru is mandatory for mantra initiation. Siddhi may never happen without (physical, living, human) guru initiation.

But recently I heard that, if there is no availability of physical living guru, then a person can write matra on a paper and after keeping it at the feet of lord Siva can start chanting the mantra.

*Which scripture* describes this procedure of attaining mantra siddhi without any initiation from 'physical, living, human' guru?

Comment: The procedure is mentioned in this answer --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29929/4732

Comment: Which of the 8 siddhi's are you hoping to acquire?

Comment: @Wikash_ I mean perfection.