# How to become a disciple of Devi and see her as Guru?

Tags: mantras, guru, devi, initiation, sadhana

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21724/procedure-to-make-gods-our-guru) question the accepted answer to which further links to this [blog post](https://www.manblunder.com/articlesview/self-initiation-of-mantras) details a procedure for one to became a disciple of Lord Dakshinamurthy. This discipleship is mainly for the purpose of mantra sadhana.

Are there any analogous procedures for entering discipleship under any aspects/forms of the Devi for at least the purpose of mantra sadhana?