# Mantra Japa without a Guru

Tags: initiation, japa

Namaskaar,

1. Can i perform Navarna mantra Japa without initiation by a Guru.
2. Can i request any random Poojari from a Maa Temple to help me in this initiation?
3. What would happen if I have already performed Japa of quite some months already? without initiation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it a sin to chant mantras without initiation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20366/is-it-a-sin-to-chant-mantras-without-initiation)

Comment: Usually not recommended to chant mantras without initiation .. neither it is good to be initiated by a temple priest .. there is also a process of getting the Goddess as the Guru in case finding a human Guru is not possible .. mentally accepting the Goddess as Guru and asking for her permission will also probably work. There is a Stotram on Goddess Bhuvaneswari where it is clearly stated that the she is there for both the initiated and the uninitiated so nothing to worry about even if you have chanted.

Comment: See this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21724/4732