# Clarifications on self-initiation to assume Dakshinamurti as guru

Tags: scripture, shiva, yoga, guru, mukti

### Background

This post [Procedure to make God(s) our Guru](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21724/procedure-to-make-gods-our-guru) gives answers and references on how one can self-initiate and assume `Dakshinamurti` as guru. Because this is a complex topic, there are a lot of concerns that are still not fully answered and true spiritual seekers might get proper guidance if these concerns can be properly addressed.

#### 1. [Krishna Trayodashi Tithi viewer drikpanchang](https://www.drikpanchang.com/panchang/tithi/daily/krishna-trayodashi-date-time.html?year=2024) says:

> "Generally, Krishna Trayodashi is considered bad for most auspicious activities. Hence it is excluded from Good Muhurat timings".

Is this tithi mentioned by `drikpanchang` same as the one which should be used for self-initiation with `Dakshinamurti`? If so, why is it saying it is generally bad, but then the self initiation is supposed to take place on this date?

#### 2. General Shastra/Yogas Education without specific Mantra

If one wants to learn Shastras from the books and then perform spiritual practices and sadhanas, for example say basic hatha yoga to begin with or any other path offered by scriptures, what mantra one should use for these generic practices? Would the self-initiation process or mantras vary if one would like to follow some other paths such as Bhakti Yoga or Gyana Yoga or Kriya Yoga or Raja Yoga? Some of these are usually recommended to be followed with an earthly physical guru only and the knowledge itself is secret or heavily guarded. Some pointers on how to overcome these limitations might be helpful as well.

#### 3. Examples of Self-Initiation with `Dakshinamurthi`

Are there any examples to take inspirations from the history?

#### 4. Guru-Dakshina

How and when would one offer `guru-dakshina` to `guru-dakshinamurthi` once self-initiated?

#### 5. Continuation with Earthly Guru

After some time of self-initiation and practices/sadhanas, if one gets an opportunity to meet an earthly physical guru, are there any prescribed processes to have multiple gurus or to transition between gurus or transition between earthly/non-earthly gurus?