# How do I find a spiritual Guru for this particular Indra sadhana?

Tags: indra, yajna, sadhana, homam

I am in need of a Guru who can help me in performing the Indra Sadhana (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOo5m4azAN8). How to perform the yagna ? Who can help me on this ? How can I prosper ?

I am very much dedicated to perform this yagna, please help me. Please don't give comments which are not related to the video nor unnecessary comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the right Guru?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2394/how-do-i-find-the-right-guru)

Comment: @BharathKashyap Personal advice questions are out of scope on Hinduism SE, so you should better change your question to be more specific like which scriptures mention the procedures/mantras for Indra Sadhana, etc.